# Search data in MS Access with spl characters from C#

Tags: c#

I want to search data from ms access table having special characters(below is the example):

CCTM-2PM/PA/14-4-1-F-SC,
 CCTM-2PM/PA/18-4-5-F-SC,
 CCTM-2PM/PA/33-20-4-F-SC,
 CCTM-2PM/PA/36-20-6-F-SC,
 CCTM-2PM/PS/22-10-1-F-SC,
 CCTM-2PM/PS/22-4-3-F-SC,
 CCTM-2PM/PS/33-20-4-F-SC(L),
 CCTM-2PM/PS/33-7-9-F-SC,
 CCTM-2PM/R-22-4-3-M-SC

The nearest match(s) results should be displayed in datagrid/combobox as you type.

is there any way to do this??

Comment: Do you mean nearest result as the nearest values in ABC order, or you would like to use some kind of fuzzy search algorythm?

Comment: ABC order is preferred..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the cleanest solution, but you could fill an IEnumerable object type with all the possible values of that field (let's call it `values`), and then query the object using LINQ:

```
var matchesBefore = (from v in values 
    where v < txtSerach.Text 
    order by v descending
    select v).Take(5); 
var matchesAfter = (from v in values 
    where v > txtSerach.Text 
    order by v ascending 
    select v).Take(5);
```

This will collect 10 values (5 before the text typed in the txtSearch textbox, and 5 after it). Then the datagrid could be filled with these values.